# UnicodeString storage type

Tags: memory-management, unicode-string, c++builder-xe

My application needs to manage a few of unicode strings (<10). The content of these strings is dynamic and can change through application run. To store strings I am using objects of type UnicodeString.

One approach to solving this problem is to create as many member variables as there are unicode strings like for example:

```
UnicodeString str1;

UnicodeString str2;

...

UnicodeString strN;
```

This solutions is pretty simple at least at first glance. But there is problem with scalability. If the number of string would rise in the future, we risk creating hard-to-read bigg code. So I thougth creating something like this for managing strings:

```
std::map<HWND, UnicodeString> file_names;    ///< member variable of form TForm1
```

Every string is connected with some edit box. I can use window handle as key to dictionary.

What I don't understand - who should be responsible for allocating and deallocating space for storing unicode string in this case? Lets say I create UnicodeString variable on local stack:

```
void TForm1::ProcessFile(TEdit *edit_box)
{
    UnicodeString str = "C:\\Temp\\ws.gdb";

    file_name[edit_box->Handle] = str;
}
```

Will the content of *str* variable survive end of member function *ProcessFile*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory storage of a `UnicodeString` is reference counted and managed by the RTL for you.  You do not need to worry about deallocating it yourself, unless you allocate the `UnicodeString` itself using the `new` operator.  In your code snippet, the `str` variable will be freed when `ProcessFile()` exits, but its contents will survive because `file_name` still has an active reference to it.

Do not use an `HWND` as the key for your `std::map`.  The window managed by the `TWinControl::Handle` property is dynamic and can change value during the lifetime of the app. You can, however, use the `TEdit*` pointer instead:

```
std::map<TEdit*, UnicodeString> file_names;

void TForm1::ProcessFile(TEdit *edit_box)
{
    UnicodeString str = "C:\\Temp\\ws.gdb";
    file_names[edit_box] = str;
}
```